# Create Page body.parent undefined

Tags: curl, notion-api

I'm trying to create a Notion page using API but keep getting error

> body failed validation: body.parent should be defined, instead was
> `undefined`.

I'm using an edited version of actual cURL code snippet from the documentation. Clearly the parent is defined. Also GET and PATCH API requests seem to work fine, it's just POST that won't.

```
curl 'https://api.notion.com/v1/pages'   -H 'Authorization: Bearer secret_SECRET'   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -H "Notion-Version: 2021-08-16"   --data '{
"parent": { "page_id": "PAGEID" }}'
```

(I removed the "properties" part from the request payload to simplify the snippet in question).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Seems to work now. My "properties" part of payload was bad but for whatever reason notion was giving out the error about "parent".

Comment: which kind of bad payload?

Comment: @JerryAn I’m not sure , I must have done something wrong but the error description threw me off. Anyway I tweaked the request changed the order of fields a bit and finally got it to work.

Comment: I got the same error message, it turned out I forgot to add  `application/json` header

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error; based on @JerryAn's comment on the other answer I added a `Content-Type: application/json` header to my POST request and it fixed the issue.